# Match each dosent fail for non existing json path

Tags: karate

I have json object in response. If I try an invalid path to extract value and assert it with match each it always passes.

```
* match each karate.jsonPath(response,"$[*].non.existing.path") == ["text1"]
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Please Not: If I give correct path and the value doesn't match with 'text1' it fails. Absolutely no issue there. Seeing issue only with invalid json path.

Comment: this is fixed in Karate 1.4.1 onwards: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2364

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas for getting this fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is by design. `match each` is actually a loop. If the number of items is zero, the `match` will never be applied.

If you want to ensure that the array needs to be non-empty, add a second check.

```
* def foo = [1, 2]
* match foo == '#[_ > 0]'
* match each foo == '#number'
```

EDIT: In Karate 1.4.1 onwards we fail this by default, but with an option for teams to revert to the old behavior. You can find more information here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2364

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Really appreciate your quick responses on Karate, It always helped!

Answer (score -1):

I faced with a situation when my response had an empty array. When i matched it with any value it was passed. Example:

```
* match each array == '#(value)'
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know you are also facing problem. However you posted it as answer, You can simply add comment to my question