# Validation fails when the array is null for karate jsonpath

Tags: validation, karate, json-path-expression

The issue is with the validation. Here when I run the tests both the validations are passing, but I could see them in the response, the price is coming as null (`price[]`). My doubt is how its finding `originalPrice` when the price array itself is null.
In the validation, I have the below ones:

And match `Response.data.abc[].price[] == '#array'`
And match `Response.data.abc[].price[].originalPrice == '#present'`.

```
Sample response:
 "data": {
    "abc": [
 "abcnumber":001,
 "price": [],
]}
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand this at all so I say "PASS" - any other karate users please help. I will close this as a duplicate of this after a few days: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639597/143475

Comment: Hi,the issue is with the validation.In the validation i have the below ones -->And match Response.data.abc[*].price[*] == '#array'
#  And match Response.data.abc[*].price[*].originalPrice == '#present'.Here when i run the tests both the validations are passing,but I could see the in the response the price is coming as null (price[]).My doubt is how its finding originalPrice when the price array itself is null.

Comment: can you please learn how to "format code" in stack overflow, edit your question and try again - with a clear example that anyone can paste into a feature and try.

Comment: Hi,I have updated the description.Hope it helps.

Comment: no it doesn't. your JSON is not well formed. I also think that karate may be too complicated for you, so I strongly recommend that you look for another tool. by well-formed I mean you should be able to paste it here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com